# Confirm message box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, reveal.js

I'm creating a confirm message box using [this plugin](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/build-a-popup-modal-window-using-the-jquery-reveal-plugin/).

```
<input type="button" id="deleteByID" value="Delete Item By ID" />
<div id="modal">
    <div id="heading">
        Are you sure you want to do that?
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <a href="#" id='revealYes' class="button green close"><img src="images/tick.png">OK</a>
        <a href="#" id='revealNo' class="button red close"><img src="images/cross.png">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
$('#deleteByID').click(function(e) {
   $('#modal').reveal({
      animation: 'fade',
      animationspeed: 320,
      closeonbackgroundclick: true,
      dismissmodalclass: 'close'
   });
   $('#revealYes,#revealNo').click(function(){
      var choice = $(this).text();
      if(choice == 'OK'){
         deleteItemInCart(item5);
         updateQtyLabel('qtyItem');
      }else{
         return false;
      }
   });  
});
```

1. I want to change the blog `#modal` into dynamic `div` as this function, how can I call this function in my page to create a `#modal` div as html above.

   ```
    function messageBox(heading, confirmMsg, cancelMsg){
      var box = ' <div id="modal"><div id="heading">'+heading+'</div><div id="content"> <a href="#" id="revealYes" class="button green close"><img src="images/tick.png">'+confirmMsg+'</a> <a href="#" id="revealNo" class="button red close"><img src="images/cross.png">'+cancelMsg+'</a>';
      return box;
   }
   ```
2. In my console,function `deleteItemInCart()` increase executing time + 1 every time I click on `OK` button. I meant, when I click on the `OK` button 1st time, the function called 1 time then the message box closed. Then click on `OK` button 2nd time, the function is call 2 times in my console. Any idea what could be causing this

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you click `$('#deleteByID')` you are creating a new click handler for `$('#revealYes,#revealNo')` that means the code that is executed

```
var choice = $(this).text();
if (choice == 'OK') {
    deleteItemInCart(item5);
    updateQtyLabel('qtyItem');
} else {
    return false;
}
```

will be executed one extra time for each time you click on `$('#deleteByID')`

change your code so that the click handler for `$('#revealYes,#revealNo')` is outside the other click handler

```
$('#deleteByID').click(function (e) {
    if($('#modal').length == 0)
        $('body').append(messageBox('heading','confirm','cancel'))
    $('#modal').reveal({
        animation: 'fade',
        animationspeed: 320,
        closeonbackgroundclick: true,
        dismissmodalclass: 'close'
    });

});

$(document).on('click','#revealYes,#revealNo',function (e) {
    var choice = $(e.target).text();
    if (choice == 'OK') {
        deleteItemInCart(item5);
        updateQtyLabel('qtyItem');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

use delegate handlers rather than bind handlers to add handlers to dynamic elements

Comment: So, how could I avoid that problem dear?

Comment: How about creating a `dynamic div` in the 1st question? Any idea DGS?

Comment: yeah added the lines `if($('#modal').length == 0)
        $('body').append(messageBox('heading','confirm','cancel'))`
just make sure to replace those strings with what you want

Comment: Done! but one thing that have to change is `var choice = $(this).attr('id'); if ($(this).attr('id') == choice) {` ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36898/discussion-between-titi-and-dgs)